# Is there any idea to mark multiple positive objects on the same image?

Tags: python, numpy, object-detection, opencv

My code is able to mark a positive sample using a rectangular box and shifts to next space on pressing enter but **I also want to mark multiple objects on a single image** what to do?

It creates box for object marking on left click.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

class BoxSelector(object):
    def __init__(self, image, window_name,color=(0,0,255)):
        #store image and an original copy
        self.image = image
        self.orig = image.copy()

        #capture start and end point co-ordinates
        self.start = None
        self.end = None

        #flag to indicate tracking
        self.track = False
        self.color = color
        self.window_name = window_name

        #hook callback to the named window
        cv2.namedWindow(self.window_name)
        cv2.setMouseCallback(self.window_name,self.mouseCallBack)

    def mouseCallBack(self, event, x, y, flags, params):
        #start tracking if left-button-clicked down
        if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.start = (x,y)
            self.track = True

        #capture/end tracking while mouse-move or left-button-click released
        elif self.track and (event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE or event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP):
            self.end = (x,y)
            if not self.start==self.end:
                self.image = self.orig.copy()
                #draw rectangle on the image
                cv2.rectangle(self.image, self.start, self.end, self.color, 2)
                if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                    self.track=False

            #in case of clicked accidently, reset tracking
            else:
                self.image = self.orig.copy()
                self.start = None
                self.track = False
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name,self.image)

    @property
    def roiPts(self):
        if self.start and self.end:
            pts = np.array([self.start,self.end])
            s = np.sum(pts,axis=1)
            (x,y) = pts[np.argmin(s)]
            (xb,yb) = pts[np.argmax(s)]
            return [(x,y),(xb,yb)]
        else:
            return []
```

This is an another python file that loop through each image and collect annotations.

```
for imagePath in list_images(args["dataset"]):

    #load image and create a BoxSelector instance
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    bs = BoxSelector(image,"Image")
    cv2.imshow("Image",image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    #order the points suitable for the Object detector
    pt1,pt2 = bs.roiPts
    (x,y,xb,yb) = [pt1[0],pt1[1],pt2[0],pt2[1]]
    annotations.append([int(x),int(y),int(xb),int(yb)])
    imPaths.append(imagePath)
```

I want to mark multiple objects such that by pressing any key I would be able to mark another positive sample on the same image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for imagePath in list_images(args["dataset"]):

    #load image and create a BoxSelector instance
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    bs = BoxSelector(image,"Image")


    while (1):
       cv2.imshow("Image",image)
        k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
        if k == ord('s'): 
            # press s, do stuff
            # order the points suitable for the Object detector
            pt1,pt2 = bs.roiPts
            (x,y,xb,yb) = [pt1[0],pt1[1],pt2[0],pt2[1]]
            annotations.append([int(x),int(y),int(xb),int(yb)])
            imPaths.append(imagePath)   

        if k == ord('r'):
            # press 'r',do stuff
            break # break skip loop and go to next image
        elif k == 27: # press esc to exit
           exit(0)
```

I would also recommend you, to enumerate over the dataset, if you want to split object marking in many sessions.

```
start_from_image = 0
for counter, image in enumerate(list_images(args["dataset"])):

    if counter >= start_from_image:
```